# Splitting a big HTML file into multiple smaller files

Tags: python, html, file

I extracted a full Discord dm as an HTML file.
It's too big to open up like that, so I wanted to split it into multiple files. I found another post here that had a solution, but I can't seem to figure out what I do wrong. Since the script opens up for 1 second and just closes afterwards with no results.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from lxml import etree, html
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path

parser = html.HTMLParser()

header= "<html><body>\n"
footer = "</body></html>\n"
i = 1
fi = 1

messagesPerFile = 3

file = "DMPim.html"

buffer = ""

try:
    tree = html.parse(StringIO(Path(file).read_text()), parser)

    try:
    # target and print all <div class="collectionDiv"> elements and subelements
        for element in tree.xpath('//div[@class="chatlog__message-group"]'):

            buffer += etree.tostring(element, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8")

            if i % messagesPerFile == 0 and i > 0:
                f = open("chat" + str(fi) + ".html", "w+")
                f.write(header + buffer + footer)
                f.close()
                fi+=1
                buffer = ""

            i+=1
        # if remaining elements are still in the buffer, write them out
        if buffer != "":
            f = open("chat" + str(fi) + ".html", "w+")
            f.write(header + buffer + footer)
            f.close()

    except etree.XPathEvalError as details:
        print ('ERROR: XPath expression', details.error_log)

except etree.XMLSyntaxError as details:
    print ('ERROR: parser', details.error_log)
```

I'm pretty new in all this and wanted this as sort of start up project, so excuse me if I'm asking obvious things.

Comment: Unless you are trying this as a learning exercise ,  a good way to approach this is to try something like Beautiful Soup lib. https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks, this is both a learning exercise and I want to use it practicly to save the images and text for memories sake. This seems like something really usefull to implement, although I want to keep the Discord html style aswell to have a better context of the messages.